# Roots of unit in a DVR

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity, valuation-theory, hensels-lemma

Let $A$ be a DVR such that its fraction field $K$ is complete w.r.t to the natural absolute value in $K$.

I am trying to prove that the projection from $A$ to the residue class field, $F$, maps the roots of unit in $A$ to the roots of unit in this field as a bijection. It is easy to show that the projection of a root of unit is a root of unit in $F$, and Hensel's lemma allow us to conclude that this is surjective. The problem is, I cannot figure how to prove it is injective, ie, if a root of unit, $x$, in $A$ is congruent to $1$ mod $m$, where $m$ is the only maximal ideal of $A$, then $x$ must be $1$. (Because then the kernel of the multiplicative homomorphism we have defined is trivial).

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: I am no expert, but I believe if you take $K$ to be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ containing a (nontrivial) $p$th root of unity and then take $A$ to be the ring of integers of this finite extension, then the finite residue field $A/m$ will be of characteristic $p$ and will consequently contain only the trivial $p$th root of unity. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: I dont think being of characterist p implies that there are no non-trivial roots of unit

Comment: He means there is no non-trivial $p$th root of unity. $x^p-1=(x-1)^p$ in a characteristic $p$ field.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it...it does not matter if this pth root is already in the p adic field, right?

Comment: That is right, the only thing important is that there is some $p$th root in the quotient field you are looking at when the residue field has characteristic $p$. Then mapping this root to the residue field will give you $1$ so the kernel is nontrivial and your map is not injective. Nevertheless, I believe that this is the only obstruction, meaning that the kernel will only consist of the $q$th roots of unity with $q$ a $p$-power and nothing else, but I am not absolutely sure about this.